# Key-Value database with key aliasing or searching by value

Tags: database, redis, key-value, key-value-store

Is there a existing in-memory production-ready KV storage that allow me to retrive a single value via any of multiple keys?

Let say I have millions of immutable entities that have a primary key associated. Any of this entity can have multiple aliases and most common scenario  is to retrieve the enity by such alias(90% of all requests). The second common scenario is to be able to retrive the entity via the primary key and after that put the new alias record(the last 10%). One special thing about this step - it always prepended by the alias searching and happens only if alias search was unsuccessful.
The entire dataset does fit into the RAM but probably doesn't if entire record data will be duplicated accross all aliases.
I'm higly concerned about data retrieval latency and less concerned on writing speed.

This can be done with Redis in two sequential lookups or via any SQL/Mongodb. I think both ways is suboptimal. The first one obviously because of two round trips for every search attempt and the second one because of latency concerns.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you check the Redis module RediSearch?

Comment: @GuyKorland no, i definetely will try it. Thanks for suggestion. Do you know if module have decent performance, comparable with Redis lookups?

Comment: It's an highly optimized module, but obviously if you'll run complex queries it will have its overhead

Answer (score 0):

Can you do two hashmaps one that goes `pk -> record data` and the other that goes from `alias -> pk` ?

Another option is to have some sort of deterministic alias so that you can go from the alias to the primary key directly in code without doing a lookup in a datastore

Comment: That wouldn't work because retrieving PK in code is costly operation(hundreds of ms) and requires network round trip, so it's used only as fallback after searching by alias.

Comment: How is a key lookup in an in memory hashmap costly operation? There is no network trip involved?

Comment: key lookup is not the costly operation. The PK retrieval itself is costly. We always have alias at hands but sometimes there is no such records associated with that alias, it can be brand new to system. On other hand searching by PK is always successful but we never have it at hands and need to do network operation + some costly computations before we can do a lookup.

Comment: So we always do a lookup by alias before falling back to searching by PK. Just to make it clear - I used term PK only for illustration purpose, as it's not sql schema there is no such thing as PK. In case you curios about what the data is:  alias is for file url, and PK is for file md5 hash.  Sorry for not describing this in the question.